# cache issue with redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having cache issues with a ruby on rails app in internet explorer.  On the client side, I am all good because I have used the following jquery code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

This adds a string to all urls with a random number like this:

```
http://www.website.com/?_=418939128471
```

The dynamically created number solves my cache issues.  The problem is that in my controllers, I have many redirects, and since they are on the backend, the jquery code is not applied and certain things that shouldn't be cached are cached.  How can i fix the redirects on the backend?  I can't switch all of them with renders.  I'd also prefer not to change my routes file as my application is quite extensive and changing my routes file would mean changing links throughout the entire application.

Thanks.

Comment: how do you decide to do redirect some requests and render others?

Comment: For more complicated controllers, I don't want the controller that is redirected_to to have variables from the old controller, so i use redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to simply pass along that random number through your redirects. The number comes through in the params as `_`, so just give that to your `redirect_to` methods:

```
redirect_to some_path('_' => params[:_])
```

That should fix it, but only do it if that param is present.

Comment: Wouldn't my routes file need to be set up to receive an argument?

Comment: Nope only the segment /seg1/seg2 need to be setup. You're free to pass along any query string params you'd like.